# Laplace transform of a random vector explained

Tags: probability-theory, laplace-transform

I have the following definition:

> Laplace transform of a random vector $X$ is the map $z \rightarrow
>  E\exp(z^T X)$

I don't understand what is $z$ here. I guess it is some vector. However why does the LT map $z$ into something, rather than $X$ into something? Why isn't the definition like this : $X \rightarrow E\exp(z^T X)$ for some vector $z$? I guess I'm missing something here, maybe a concrete example would help

Answer (score 0):

As you have written, $X$ is a *random variable*. This means that $X$ takes values distributed according to a certain probability law. A random variable cannot be used as an independent variable as you have proposed, because it takes unpredictable values.

Let us take an example with a vector of dimension 1. So $X$ is a one-dimensional random vector, it is a random number and let's say it can take the value $1$ with probability $1/2$ and the value $0$ with probability $1/2$. Let us compute the map $z\mapsto \mathbb{E}[\exp(zX)]$. For any complex number $z$, we have 
$$ \mathbb{E}[\exp(zX)]=\frac12\exp\left(z\times1\right)+\frac12\exp\left(z\times0\right)=\frac{\mathrm e^{z}+1}2.$$
The Laplace transform of $X$ is the *function* $\phi:z\mapsto\frac{\mathrm e^{z}+1}2$.

Generally speaking, the Laplace transform of a random variable is a function that contains all possible informations concerning $X$. One always has $\phi(0)=1$. One can extract from it the mean value of $X$ as $$\overline{X}=\phi'(0)=\frac12$$
and many other properties. It is handier than manipulating probabilities and also more efficient.